# How use other models into one model without association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

adding to question: I have model A, B, C.   I need, in the Model A, the methods of model B and C, but not throug association.

**Edit:**  In the model B, for example, can be a Shopping Cart, where I need to update the Session var, and update Product model.  I know that can not use Session var in a model, but in module maybe yes (I have no certainty), but the idea is use other models to access a other relationships.

can you help me?.

grettings.

**Edit 2:**

My super duper solution!  Inheritance.

> A < C

and

> B < C

Comment: There is not really enough info. Could you please provide a specific example. It's difficult to answer such a vague question

Answer (score 1):

Refactor the necessary methods of Model B and Model C into a module, then include that module in Model A, Model B, and Model C.

Comment: And in that module, can I use ActiveRecord?

Comment: You could.  I think we need more information in the question - what are the methods you are trying to use?  Are they domain methods, like `calculate_total` that you might see on a `ShoppingCart` class?  Or are they traditional ActiveRecord attrs like `first_name`?

Comment: ok. I updated the question. the idea is like ShoopingCart, I want use other models into a model.